# Highcharts Polar Chart: Multiple pane segment colors

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to change the background color of each of the segments of a polar chart. It's easy to set a singular color for the background, but is it possible to set a different color for each piece of the polar pie?

An example would be 8 different colors for the chart segments below:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no easy way to do this within the API.

I'll present a solution that utilizes the `chart.renderer` to draw a single color for each slice of your polar chart:

```
var colors = [ "pink", "yellow", "blue", "red", "green", "cyan", "teal", "indigo" ];    
var parts = 8;

for(var i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    chart.renderer.arc(chart.plotLeft + chart.yAxis[0].center[0], 
                       chart.plotTop + chart.yAxis[0].center[1], 
                       chart.yAxis[0].height, 
                       0, 
                       -Math.PI + (Math.PI/(parts/2) * i), 
                       -Math.PI + (Math.PI/(parts/2) * (i+1))).attr({
        fill: colors[i % colors.length],
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'opacity': 1
    }).add();
}
```

Click [this JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/U72kp/3/) to see a live demonstration.

It uses the [`renderer.arc`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.arc) to draw each slice with the information from `chart` about center and axis height. The arcs are drawn using start and end angle, given in radians. The various slices can be colored using the `colors` array, and the number of slices can be controlled with the `parts` variable.

If there are more parts than colors it will start from the beginning of the `colors` array when it runs out of colors, using `colors[i % colors.length]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fake column series with differently colored points and set yAxis.maxPadding to 0:

```
chart: {
polar: true,
events: {
  load: function() {
    var chart = this,
      max = chart.yAxis[0].max;
    chart.addSeries({
      type: 'column',
      data: [{
        y: max,
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2)'
      }, {
        y: max,
        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2)'
      }, {
        y: max,
        color: 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }, {
        y: max,
        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'
      }, {
        y: max,
        color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)'
      }, {
        y: max,
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)'
      }, {
        y: max,
        color: 'rgba(130, 70, 150, 0.2)'
      }, {
        y: max,
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
      }],
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      zIndex: 0,
      showInLegend: false,
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      animation: false
    })
  }
}
},

yAxis: {
  maxPadding: 0
},
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tsj9pomq

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.maxPadding